# Do binary numbers move in sequence ones and zeros or parallel at once to ALU for addition?

Tags: binary, alu

Do binary numbers move in sequence ones and zeros or parallel at once to ALU for addition, I mean ones and zeros in sequence vertically to ALU or parallel horizontally AT ONCE?

Comment: there is no vertical or horizontal orientation for binary bits ..... are you looking at a picture?

Answer (score 4):

yes.

parallel and serial adders both exist. most modern computers are parallel.